# Why can't PHPMyAdmin write to my config directory on my AWS Ubuntu 12.04 LTS instance?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I know that this is a very common question to find asked, but I'm having serious difficulty with this on my AWS Ubuntu 12.04 instance.

I installed PHPMyAdmin using apt-get with the command `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` and it installed just fine. I can use PHPMyAdmin as it is on the instance.

I'm trying to generate a config file using the setup wizard, and I followed the steps as documented on the PHPMyAdmin website to set that up. I created the config directory in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and gave it world write access using `sudo chmod 777 config`. Despite all of this, PHPMyAdmin still tells me that my config directory is not writable.

I then tried to create a config directory in `/etc/phpmyadmin` which also had world write access and I'm still not having any luck!

Can anyone please tell me if I'm missing something here? I don't know what else I can try to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

My config directory is actually `/var/lib/phpmyadmin`.

I found this from the index.lib.php file in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib`. There's a function in there called `check_config_rw()` which checks the Config directory based on the currently used config.inc.php file. Changing the permissions on this folder and its contents to make it www-data writable solved my problem!